# What does "bleed-over" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> “and digital products are there to promote maximal engagement. It makes it hard to disengage, and leads to a lot of **bleed-over** into the family routine.”

Comment: It's not a very common phrase, but it means the same as 'contamination'. It means that something which should stay in one domain crosses over into another domain. Imagine you are doing a watercolour painting, and the green paint of the grass 'bleeds' into the blue paint of the sky, which is not what you want to happen.

Comment: I think it's a printing term, used figuratively